# Start process as other user as administrator c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-7

I have the need to install something as an admin. As it is not possible to give the user admin rights I need to specify a admin account. My current code:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToSomeFileMsiFile.msi)
            {
                Arguments = " /q "
            };
info.UserName = "usernamer";
info.Domain = "dm";
info.Password = securePasswordString;
info.LoadUserProfile = false;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(info);
```

I get the error:

```
{"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."}
```

It seems that if I set UseShellExecute = true, I can start as Administrator and if I set it false, I can start as other user.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `msiexec.exe` with a [command line parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Install) of the msi file.

```
msiexec.exe /i /q somepackage.msi
```

So your updated code would be:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe")
        {
            Arguments = " /i " + varableWithSomeMSIFilename + " /q"
        };
```

Comment: Arguments = " /i /q C:\file.msi" is only opening the msiexec.exe /? dialog

Comment: @Anubis1233 Put an `@ `in front of the quotes to prevent it from parsing escape sequences.  `\f` is the escape sequence for a Form Feed character.  Or just put it into a variable and append it, like in my example

Comment: I did put a @ in front of it it did not change something. In fact I first tested with the @^^. with \\ it does not work too

Comment: @Anubis1233 it seems that the /q is causing problems. Try putting it after the MSI file, as in my updated answer.

Comment: well and how do I start it as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Set : info.UseShellExecute = true;

An example :

```
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();

  proc.UserName = "usernamer";
proc.Domain = "dm";
proc.Password = securePasswordString;
proc.LoadUserProfile = false;

    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
    proc.Verb = "runas";

            try
            {
                Process.Start(proc);
            }
            catch

            {
                // The user refused the elevation.
                // Do nothing and return directly ...
                return;
            }

            Application.Exit();  // Quit itself
```

Comment: this will result in a InvalidOperationException. Because then I cannot start as a other user

Comment: is it possible to open a cmd and run from there?

Comment: The current solution will not work as it will start as admin, but not with thre correct user

Comment: Read my first comment, the exception will occur

Comment: Just add username, domain, etc. that you already have into your code.

Comment: Is this working for you? I cannot say UseShellExecute  = true if I specifiy a user

Comment: Add/update in Application Manifest File : <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: This will result in asking the user to provide admin credentials. Which is not programm code.

Comment: info.LoadUserProfile = true; Sorry my mistake

Comment: I cannot confirm this as working either. It Seems to me that there is no such solution to do it both without user interaction